# Using __set() with Array Append Syntax

Tags: php

I have a magic `__set($name, $value)` method. Within `__set()`, Is there a way I can detect if the array append short-hand was used so it doesn't blow away pre-existing values?

```
class Foo extends ArrayObject {

  protected $bar = array();

  public function __set($name, $value) {
    $this->bar = $value; // I want to handle both replace AND append
  }
}

$foobar = new Foo;
$foobar->bar = array('first element');
$foobar->bar[] = 'new element';
```

How can I handle this situation?

Comment: This code does not even run for me since `bar` is `protected`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `__get` to achieve what you want.

```
class Foo {

  protected $bar = array();

  public function &__get($name) {
    return $this->$name;
  }

  public function __set($name, $value) {
    $this->$name = $value;
  }
}

$foobar = new Foo;
$foobar->bar = array('first element');
$foobar->bar[] = 'new element';
print_r($foobar->bar);
```

This is because the `[]=` operation first reads the property, then appends the element.

Note that `__get` must return 'by reference' for this to work (at least in PHP 5.4); if it does not return by reference you get a notice about indirect modification.

**NOTE:** also, at this point, you'd probably be as well making it public as the effect is basically the same.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using array access, PHP is going to dynamically create a public member called `bar` on your `$foobar` instance. One way to accomplish this is to use the `ArrayAccess` implementation provided by `ArrayObject`, like such:

```
$foobar = new Foo;
$foobar['baz'] = array('first element');
$foobar['baz'][] = 'new element';
```

Note, however, this will create a public property called `baz`, and it *will not* make use of the magic property methods (`__set()`, `__get()`, `__isset()`, `__unset()`)